# Java String Manipulation into Columns

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I'm working on a tool and am required to split text into columns.

For example - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1

Would return this if the period is 2 - 
1,3,5,7,9
and 
2,4,6,8,1

IF the period is 3 - 
1,4,7,1 and
2,5,8 and
3,6,9

Etc etc. 
I'm struggling to construct this alogirithm, any help would be appreciated!  How is best to go about constructing these sort of algorithms? I've written it down on paper but can't transfer into code! I'm stuck on constructing a second loop to increase the period. Here's an example of what I have so far

```
    String to_test = "1234567891";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int period = 2;
    int startAt = 0;
    int characterToCheck = 0; 

    while (startAt < period) {
        for (int i = 0; i < to_test.length(); i++) {
            if (i % period == 0) {
                sb.append(to_test.charAt(characterToCheck));
            }
            characterToCheck++;
        }
        // String is constructed
        System.out.println(sb);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        startAt ++;
        characterToCheck = startAt; 
    }

}
```

Comment: i think char array is easy way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Tester1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String to_test = "1234567891";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

        char[] charArray = to_test.toCharArray();

        int period = 3;

        for (int j=0;j<period;j++){
            for (int i=j;i<charArray.length;i+=period){
                sb.append(charArray[i]);
            }
            sb.append(";");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in a single for loop and fill `n` StringBuilder (`n = period`)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder[] ret = period("1234567891", 3);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ret));
}

public static StringBuilder[] period(String s, int period) {
    StringBuilder[] ret = new StringBuilder[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < period; i++) {
        ret[i] = new StringBuilder();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        ret[i % period].append(s.charAt(i));
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This will work for you. No hard-coding required :)

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1234567891";
    int period = 3;
    List<List<String>> stringList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    // Initializing number of lists required based on period. 
    for (int i = 0; i < period; i++) {
        List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        stringList.add(l1);
    }
   // debug this part of code :P. I am adding the digits based on period length
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length();) {
        for (int j = 0; j < period; j++) {
            if (i > s.length() - 1)
                break;
            stringList.get(j).add(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
            i++;
        }
    }
// Displaying list of lists 
    for (List<String> ls : stringList) {
        for (String str : ls) {
            System.out.print(" " + str);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
 1 4 7 1
 2 5 8
 3 6 9
```

for period = 2 :

```
 1 3 5 7 9
 2 4 6 8 1
```

for period = 4:

```
 1 5 9
 2 6 1
 3 7
 4 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created this small function for it, basically the while loop you were using was a for loop anyway.

public static void toColumn(String to_test, int period) {

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0;i<period;i++){
        for(int j=i;j<to_test.length();j+= period){
            sb.append(to_test.charAt(j));
        }
        sb.append('\n');
    }

    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this (which is not the most efficiency solution):

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo(String aString, int period){
        List<ArrayList<String>> out = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        for(int i = 0; i < period; i++){
            out.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        }

        int i = 0;

        while(i < aString.length()){
            for(int j = 0; j < period && i < aString.length(); j++){
                out.get(i % period).add(String.valueOf(aString.charAt(i)));
                i++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

output:

```
new Foo("1234567891", 1); // output [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]]
new Foo("1234567891", 2); // output [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 1]]
new Foo("1234567891", 3); // output [[1, 4, 7, 1], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: If you like answers, on SO you can give users reputation and you can accept the better answer. @JavaNoob

Answer (score 0):

When looking at this problem from a mathmatical point of view, you can easily determine, that you can use an array to store your values and *division* and *modulo* to calculate the indices:

```
final char[][] result = new char[period][yourString.length() / period + ((yourString.length() % period) > 0 ? 1 : 0)];    

IntStream.range(0, yourString.length()).forEach(index -> result[index % period][index / period] = yourString.charAt(index));
```

Thats it.

When running tests for different values for `period`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String to_test = "1234567891";

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        final int period = i;

        // create result array based on input values
        final char[][] result = new char[period][to_test.length() / period + ((to_test.length() % period) > 0 ? 1 : 0)];

        // iterate over the characters and assign each character to the right array index
        IntStream.range(0, to_test.length())
                .forEach(index -> result[index % period][index / period] = to_test.charAt(index));

        // print the calculated result
        System.out.println("Period = " + period);
        for (char[] line : result) {
            for (int j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
                // print character and check if trailing ',' is need
                System.out.print(line[j] + ((j < line.length - 1 && line[j + 1] != '\0')? ", " : ""));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

you get this **output**:

```
Period = 1
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1 

Period = 2
1, 3, 5, 7, 9 
2, 4, 6, 8, 1 

Period = 3
1, 4, 7, 1 
2, 5, 8

Period = 4
1, 5, 9
2, 6, 1
3, 7
```

Comment: @JavaNoob You are welcome. Please mark the answer that helped you the most as `Accepted`.